# Use callback function on 2 multidimensional arrays whenever there are similarities based on the key

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-9

I have 2 multidimensional arrays:
1 that contains all data

```
[
    "workflowStep" => null,
    "penalty" => 0.0,
    "order" => 0,
    "readMode" => true,
    "applyPenaltyTo101Only" => false,
    "writeMode" => true,
    "transMemory" => [
            'uid' => 'FS#GEHED',
            'items' => 12,
        ],
    "targetLocale" => "en_us",
]
```

1 that contains datatype casts for the data

```
[
    "penalty" => 'float',
    "readMode" => 'bool',
    "transMemory" => [
            'uid' => 'string',
            'items' => 'int',
        ],
]
```

I want to go over every value in the data array and apply the datatype casts to the values by using some sort of callback function.

So my question is: How can loop over every item in the data array that has a corresponding key in the casts array so that I can apply the cast to the data array values?

Comment: `decimal` does not exist as a type you could cast into, in PHP.

Comment: @CBroe that is not what the question is about

Comment: But us being able to answer your question, requires that what you want is actually _possible_. If you want to do something else, other than an _actual_ cast, for this pseudo-type - then you need to specify, what.

Comment: I've edited the question can you give me an answer?

Comment: Basically, something trivial like this should do: https://3v4l.org/0DB4oC But you will have to replace the `settype` call with something more appropriate - something that a) handles your `decimal` type, and b) also takes care of edge cases, like if your input contained `"readMode" => "false",`, then a simple cast to boolean would still result in `true`. So for that part, you'll probably best implement a `switch` statement that handles each of these data types appropriately.